# How can i ensure that only unique objects are created in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, unique

This was an interview question and I was blank with no thoughts whatsoever.
Suppose I have an Employee class having three fields `EmpId`, `EmpName`, `EmpAddress`.

Now my job is to ensure that all objects that I create will be unique on the basis of `EmpId` such that when I try to create two objects with same `EmpId`, there has to be a mechanism to stop/alert me about it, maybe a compiler alert or any logic would do.

Only thing I could come up in the interview was to use `Map` (i.e HashMap) having key as `EmpId` to ensure uniqueness.
I know primary key in DB ensures this but how can I handle this in Java itself.

Any suggestions/thoughts on such line will be appreciated.

Comment: *"compiler wont allow me to do so"* Are you sure about that part of the assignment?

Comment: It sounds like you need to generate the `EmpId` in a manner that ensures uniqueness, and not let a user create an arbitrary value. A synchronized static factory method could work for this. A synchronized factory method could also work for your Map idea.

Comment: Your solution seems fine. A `static long` counter with synchronized access would be a simpler solution.

Comment: Well if frameworks are allowed, this can easily be done using Hibernate with primary key annotation in java.

Comment: Like @GherbiHicham has said, I would wire this with a database. Every time you want to insert a new row with a duplicated key, you'll get an exception.

Comment: `EmpId` has to be passed as constructor parameter? If not, you can go with a suggestion from @MadPhysicist.

Comment: @JanezKuhar. You can do both. Pass in whatever you want, ignore it, and use a counter or factory or whatever :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of lots of ways.  For example<sup>1</sup>:

1. Use a conventional Map that maps EmpId to Employee.
2. Use a Set of EmpIds.
3. Use a database table where each row represents an Employee and the EmpId is the primary key.
4. Use a sequence generator<sup>2</sup> to generate a sequence of unique EmpId values, and don't allow the caller of the Employee object constructor to supply an EmpId.
5. If the EmpId is an integer and the space is dense, use a bitmap or BitSet rather than a Set of EmpIds.
6. If the EmpId is an integer and the space is really dense, you could use a TreeMap to represent ranges of EmpIds.  (The logic is a bit complicated.)

---

<sup>1 - There are various other "poor" solutions that I won't enumerate.</sup>

<sup>2 - This is not really solving the problem **as stated**.  However, this is possibly how you would implement this in practice; e.g. using an SQL SEQUENCE.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can solve your problem using **HashSet** or another implementation of the Class **Set** and *overriding* the method *equals* to avoid duplicated entry of the class.

> *from the Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of the class Set*
>
> Many methods in Collections Framework interfaces are defined in terms
> of the equals method.

***N.B.** HashSet and Set implement the interface Collection*

I will show you an example that avoid the duplicate using the method *contains*

> *from the Java [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of the method contains of the class Set*
>
> boolean contains(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this collection contains
> the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this
> collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ?
> e==null : o.equals(e)).

In this code I used a static HashSet to have an unique list of **Employee**. You can insert elements in the set only using the method **addToSet** that return *true* only if the you successfully insert the element in the HashSet.

```
import java.util.HashSet; 

public class Employee {
    private static HashSet<Employee> EmpSet= new HashSet<>();
    private String EmpId, EmpName, EmpAddress;
    
    public Employee(String id, String name, String addr){
        EmpId = id;
        EmpName = name;
        EmpAddress = addr;
    }
    
    public static boolean addToSet(Employee employee){  //this can be synchronized if you need
        if(EmpSet.contains(employee))
            return false;
        else
            EmpSet.add(employee);
        return true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object to_compare){
        if( !(to_compare instanceof Employee))
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) to_compare;
        return this.EmpId.equals(other.EmpId);
    }
}
```

The shown code works also if EmpId is Integer or Long.
If you are using this class from multiple threads you can make the method *addToSet* synchronized as suggested in the comments.

If you are using a DB this code is not valid, you can find specific methods for that specifica case.

**Edit**
I am sorry, actually you don't need the method addToSet because the method *add* of the class **HashMap** do exactly the same, so you can use its method or simply:

```
public static boolean addToSet(Employee employee){  //this can be synchronized if you need
                EmpSet.add(employee);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people have said, you can use a `Map` or a `Set` to hold you collection, and override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods to ensure proper use in collections.

If you wanted to check on creation of the object, you could e.g. use a `Map` and throw an exception:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;    

public class Employee {

    private static Map<EmpID, Employee> employees = new HashMap<EmpID, Employee>();

    private EmpId empID;
    private EmpName empName;
    private EmpAddress address;

    public Employee(EmpID empID, EmpName empName, EmpAddress empAddress) throws NotUniqueIDException {            
        if(!employees.keySet().contains(empID) {
            this.empID = empID;
            this.empName = empName;
            this.empAddress = empAddress;
            employees.put(empID, this);
        } else {
            // Error
            throw NotUniqueIDException();
        }
    }
```

And then, when using:

```
try {
    Employee employee = new Employee(empID, empName, empAddress);
} catch(NotUniqueIDException exception) {
    // Do something here
}
```

As for if you needed to generate unique IDs, `UUID.randomUUID()` might be something to look at

Answer (score -1):

Simple we need to override equals() method and golden rule says when ever you overrides equals() we must override hascode().
Here is working code for this

```
    class Employee
    {
        private Integer id;
        private String firstname;
        private String lastName;
        private String department;
    
        Employee(Integer id, String firstname, String lastName, String department) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.department = department;
        }
    
        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }
        
        public String getFirstname() {
            return firstname;
        }
        
        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
        
        public String getDepartment() {
            return department;
        }
        
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(o == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (o == this)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (getClass() != o.getClass())
            {
                return false;
            }
    
            Employee e = (Employee) o;
            return (this.getId() == e.getId());
        }
        
    
        public int hashCode()
        {
            final int PRIME = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = PRIME * result + getId();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Driver Class

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(100,"Arpit","Agarwal","SDET");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(101,"Neha","Agrawal","Web Developer");
        Employee e3 = new Employee(103,"Priya","Gupta","Data Science");
        Employee e4 = new Employee(100,"Mohit","Verma","Dev ops");
        Set<Employee> mySet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        mySet.add(e1);
        mySet.add(e2);
        mySet.add(e3);
        mySet.add(e4);
        for(Employee obj : mySet)   {
            System.out.println(obj.getId() + ", " + obj.getFirstname() + ", " + obj.getLastName() + ", " + obj.getDepartment());
        }
    }
}
```